# JS d3 scale time doesn't produce the correct ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to generate `ticks` based on a start and end time. I'm using the `scaleTime` function from d3, passing the `domain` and the `range`.

```
const scale = scaleTime().domain([1625733909077, 1625733911965]).range([0, 1317]);
```

When I log `scale.ticks()` I'm getting this output:
[image]

This seems to be correct because it takes something like 2.5 seconds.

But when I try to extract the `ms` value from each:

```
console.log(ticks.map((v) => v.getMilliseconds()).sort());
```

I'm getting this output:

```
[0, 0, 200, 200, 200, 400, 400, 400, 600, 600, 600, 800, 800, 800]
```

Which is not what I expect. **The result I expect in this case is:**

```
[0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 2200, 2400, 2600]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's working as intended. `getMilliseconds` won't return something 1000 or over. Those are seconds.  The function does not convert seconds to milliseconds.

Based on your comments, it looks like you want an array of the number of milliseconds from your scale's domain minimum.

```
ticks.map(x =>  x - ticks[0])
```

Comment: So how can I get the result I expect?

Comment: Are you looking to express each date as the number of milliseconds from a certain time? if so, what time?

Comment: I provide a start and end time to produce a scale. I want each tick to be an ms representation of the scale. See the expected array in the question. Think about a performance timeline.